# Choose header content from entity-reference dropdown?

Tags: views, 7, theming, entities

Been struggling with this for a while... I know there is probably a fairly easy way to accomplish it but I haven't been able to figure it out.

The goal:
When a user creates a new page for the site, I would like them to be able to choose from several different headers using a drop-down list. I know I can set up blocks for the different headers and use the built-in functionality to have them appear on different content types or pages, but for various reasons I would like to have the header as a custom field within the page content type.

I have created a "Header Content" content type and used the Entity Reference module to populate a select list field in the page content type. I can display the selected option or the rendered entity it refers to in the body of my page without any trouble.

What I can't figure out is how to display the rendered entity in the header section instead of the main content.

Put another way: When creating a new page or editing an existing one, the user should be able to select existing nodes from a drop-down list (this part is done). The selected node should show up in the header region (this part is giving me trouble).

I think it could be accomplished in one of two ways:

1) Using Views:
I tried creating a views block to read either the reference or rendered content from the parent page and display it in the header (or wherever I place the block) but I can't seem to get the relationship right.

2) Using a custom module
This seems pretty straightforward but I'm not sure how to reference the value of "field_header" (the name of my custom field using hooks. I'm also not sure if the data will be available if I configure field_header not to display in the configuration.

This seems like a problem that's likely to be solved already. Maybe I'm not phrasing it correctly when I search because I haven't been able to find any examples to help me solve it.

Answer (score 1):

What I'm 99% sure you want is the [Header Image module](http://drupal.org/project/headerimage). It works by being able to select a piece of (node) content to place in some region thats been pre-defined.

Eg, put an image in some header region of your site. Or text or whatever ....

Comment: Thanks Tenken, but I'm using 7.x... perhaps I should've mentioned that...
Header Image doesn't have a 7.x version. I think I'll take a look and see if I can't get it to work anyway.

Comment: there is a 7x version in the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/1259580). I know because I'm using it :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... looks pretty good but the important thing I was looking for was the ability to choose the header from a drop-down when creating the page. As far as I can tell, the module only works from the other direction -- assigning nodes to the header.

I was able to hack it together by editing page.tpl with the following:

```
// If the current node has a field called "field_header" and that field has content
if( $field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_header', $node->language) ) {
    $nid = $field['0']['target_id'];
    $delta = 0;
    $language = 'und';

    $entity = entity_load('node', array($nid));
    $header_content = $entity[$nid]->body[$language][$delta]['value'];
}
if ( !empty( $header_content ) ) {
    // Hacked together replacement for header content
    echo '<div class="region region-header"><div class="block-inner clearfix">';
    print render($header_content);
    echo '</div></div>';
}
else {
    // Render original header content
    print render($page['header']);
}
```

I'm sure there are a zillion better ways to accomplish this -- and I plan to figure out a few when I have time. For now, this works pretty well considering I already had blocks set up with header content that now act as fallbacks.

Thanks again for your help -- I'd love to see any other pointers. This is my first Drupal site and I'm very impressed and a little intimidated so far.